# Production web site is breaking sometimes

Tags: caching

My production site (Drupal 7) is breaking sometimes. It seems the styles are not taking. all the images & text not aligned well. It will work perfectly when we clear the cache. In this site, we have used Boost Beta version module & cache expiration module. This site contains lot of images. It is a dynamic site.

Is it the problem with Boost? In some site it is saying that need to check the Bandwidth optimization (Aggregate and compress CSS files & Aggregate JavaScript files). I didn't check that. Some times there is no problem. sometimes it breaks. This is happening only for anonymous user.

Anyone please help me?

Comment: This seems strange because when you clear the cache it is fine. But once the cache is cleared the same CSS should be served from thereon (unless it is done conditionally). Only content might get stale until the next cache clear. Does it work fine after a cache clear, and then somehow revert to the previous CSS? I will make a copy of the CSS file when it is fine, and a copy when it is not fine and inspect it. Also, look at serving all of your CSS with every page load from info file), instead of having it done conditionally.

Comment: This is happening only for anonymous user.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have caching for Anonymous users set - try disabling all caching, and all caching modules - see if that works.

Comment: I didn't enabled any cache for Anonymous user in the performance page. anyway I am going to un-install th eboost module